# Java, WSDL generated class cannot be cast to javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement

Tags: java, spring, jaxb, wsdl

I am getting back an javax.xml.bind.JAXBElementexception after calling a web service.

```
JAXBElement<ShowPendingFiles> jAXBElement = new ObjectFactory().createShowPendingFiles(showPendingFilesRequest);

CustomEnvelopeDetails customEnvelopeDetails = new CustomEnvelopeDetails(
    CcrConstants.ACTION_PENDING_FILES,
    new SecurityHeader(isSecurityEnabled, username, password)
        );

final Object marshalled = (ShowPendingFilesResponse) createServiceTemplate(jaxb2Marshaller)
//return (ShowPendingFilesResponse) createServiceTemplate(jaxb2Marshaller)
    .marshalSendAndReceive(soapServer, jAXBElement,
          new SoapRequestHeaderModifier(customEnvelopeDetails));
return (ShowPendingFilesResponse) marshalled;
```

The web service reponds with 200 OK and the response in XML is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns2:showPendingFilesResponse
            xmlns:ns2="http://iris.somewhere.com/web_services/external/downloadFile"
            xmlns:ns3="http://iris.somewhere.gr/web_services/external/uploadFile"/>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

which is correct, since there are no "files available to download" yet.

However the **marshalSendAndReceive** fails to marshal the response.

I am getting the following exception:

> javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement cannot be cast to
> download.iris.models.ShowPendingFilesResponse

The auto generated (from WSDL) JAX class is this one

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "showPendingFilesResponse", propOrder = {
    "showPendingFilesResult"
})
public class ShowPendingFilesResponse {

    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    protected List<TransferableFile> showPendingFilesResult;

   
    public List<TransferableFile> getShowPendingFilesResult() {
        if (showPendingFilesResult == null) {
            showPendingFilesResult = new ArrayList<TransferableFile>();
        }
        return this.showPendingFilesResult;
    }

}
```

Comment: A `JAXBElement` isn't a `ShowPendingFilesResponse`, it wraps one. Cast it to a `JAXBElement` and use `getValue()` to get the actual object.

Comment: all mu services work with something like return (ShowPendingFilesResponse) createServiceTemplate(jaxb2Marshaller). What is the problem in this one? Why the getValue() method is needed in this particular case and not the always? Is this somehow related with the @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)?

Comment: No that is what is being generated due to your xsd. I don't care what your services state, the implementation needs to be as I stated in my earlier comment. You basically do the same for the request (wrap it in a `JAXBElement`) for the response you have to do the opposite unwrap it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from the request you are sending

```
JAXBElement<ShowPendingFiles> jAXBElement = new ObjectFactory().createShowPendingFiles(showPendingFilesRequest);
```

The request is wrapped in a `JAXBElement` for the response you need to do the inverse unwrap it. As the result you are getting is (judging from the exception you are getting) a `JAXBElement<ShowPendingFilesResponse>` and not a `ShowPendingFilesResponse` directly.

Modify your code accordingly.

```java
final JAXBElement<ShowPendingFilesResponse> marshalled = (JAXBElement<ShowPendingFilesResponse>) createServiceTemplate(jaxb2Marshaller)
    .marshalSendAndReceive(soapServer, jAXBElement, new SoapRequestHeaderModifier(customEnvelopeDetails));
return marshalled.getValue();
```